# Symfony Doctrine Nested Set Path To Root Query

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, nested-sets

Is there a way in symfony to get from a doctrine nested set the whole path/route from a specified by id element to the root element in a Doctrine_Collection or array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should return what you are after:

```
$obj->getNode()->getAncestors();
```

From the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_node_nestedset.html#getAncestors())

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of building something like a breadcrumb trail, getPath would do it:

```
getPath
public string getPath(string seperator, mixed includeRecord, bool includeNode)

gets path to node from root, uses record::toString() method to get node names

Parameters:
    seperator - path seperator
    includeNode - whether or not to include node at end of path
Returns:
    string representation of path
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_node_nestedset.html#getPath%28%29

So you need to override __toString() in your model. If you don't, Doctrine will try to guess what to write by looking for columns called "name", "title" and the like.